# How to use XCTAssertThrowsSpecific

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, nsexception, xctest

I'm writing Cocoa unit tests using XCTest and recently used XCTAssertThrows for the first time. That's pretty cool, but I want to make it even better with XCTAssertThrowsSpecific and requiring a certain exception.

Here is an example test:

```
-(void)testShortPassword {
    XCTAssertThrows([user storePassword:@"abc"],@"Expect exception for short pw");
}
```

And on my user class I have the following code:

```
-(void)storePassword:(NSString*)password {

    NSCAssert(password.length > 6, @"Password must be longer than 6 characters");

    // go on to store the password on the keychain
}
```

Keeping in mind that Cocoa in general shies away from using exceptions (so it might be better to return an error, and show UI in the preceding example, etc.) How do I throw an exception in a manner that can be caught by `XCTAssertThrowsSpecific`? How do I specify that in `XCTAssertThrowsSpecific(expression, specificException, format...)`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**You should only use exceptions for exceptional cases, not for error handling and flow control**

Having said that, here's how you use `XCTAssertThrowsSpecific`:

`XCTAssertThrowsSpecific` expects the specific class of the exception as the second parameter. `NSCAssert` throws an `NSException`. To test for that, use

```
XCTAssertThrowsSpecific([object methodThatShouldThrow], NSException, @"should throw an exception");
```

Now, that won't help much, because it's likely that every exception is an `NSException` or a subclass thereof.

`NSException`s have a `name` property that determines the type of the exception. In case of `NSCAssert` this is `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. To test for that, use `XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed`

```
XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed(
  [object methodThatShouldThrow],
  NSException,
  NSInternalInconsistencyException,
  @"should throw NSInternalInconsistencyException"
);
```

Comment: do you still think this since Swift 2.0? Thanks

Comment: Swift 2 doesn't add *exception* handling, it adds _error_ handling. The main semantic difference is that exceptions are unrecoverable, whereas errors are can be handled gracefully.

Comment: Thanks, also FYI XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed isn't in Swift 2.0

Comment: @Sebastian could you elaborate on why you avoid using Exceptions for error-handling? I too, use them for validation and they've helped keep things neat so far - is the performance penalty massive?

Comment: In short, because Apple says so: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000012-BAJGFBFB

Comment: How can I use this in swift , because I just started iOS and I don't the objective C.  Please help me out